# Why are hentai censored?

Tags: censorship, law

Why do Japanese censor hentai while they themselves also produce a myriad of uncensored lewd videos where you can see everything clearly? Isn't this just absurd? Besides, the nature of hentai as well makes the censorship beyond common sense.

The common defense by Japanese against the criticism on lolicon anime is, no one in real life is harmed. Then, I would like to ask the question, who could be harmed by not censoring hentai?

Comment: "[...] while they themselves also produce a myriad of uncensored lewd videos where you can see everything clearly?" JAVs are censored just as hard if not harder, under the same laws.

Comment: @蛞蝓真宵 well OP might want to ask about that but that's off-topic here? And wherever OP asks that, why can't someone else say 'hentai does the same' and so you get a catch-22 ?